# Do postdoc mentors in math provide their mentees with research problems?

Tags: mathematics, postdocs

I don't understand how it's possible to write a large number of papers in good journals without someone advising their research still, past the grad student phase.

Comment: This only means that you have not met some really strong postdocs/young researchers.

Comment: The strongest mathematicians I know came up with their own dissertation problems - they didn't need problem suggestions even as a grad student.

Comment: I don't understand how it's possible to find and execute a criss-cross squeeze at the bridge table.  I also don't understand how it's possible to throw a baseball at 90 mph.

Answer (score 7):

I had a very strong postdoc whom I seduced to work on some of my projects instead of the stuff he did in his PhD thesis. That resulted in 7 or 8 joint papers over several years of collaboration that I (and, I hope, he too) can be proud of. So the answer to the question in the title is "occasionally yes" even if the postdoc is very strong and capable of completely independent work.

On the other end of the spectrum, I had a graduate student who came in with his own research idea and the only thing I have ever suggested to him was the formulation of a certain lemma that in my opinion was right in the middle between where he was and where he wanted to be. He managed to prove that lemma and then to derive the result he really wanted from it, and that was essentially all advising that I did (except for signing various bureaucratic papers and reminding him that if he didn't do this or that by the deadline, the defense would have to be moved to a later date).

In general, there are people who prefer to work alone and there are people who like to collaborate with anybody they meet, regardless of whether they are graduate students, postdocs or senior mathematicians. It is merely a matter of personality and circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

My postdoc mentor did suggest some problems, but they weren't the right fit for me and I never ended up working on them too much.  My side project from when I was a PhD (note my dissertation wasn't publishable), which was largely in collaboration with the postdoc whose office was next to mine as a grad student, turned out to be a good line of research that got me to a tenure-track job and tenure - in a university with a low ranked PhD program.

I wouldn't say I turned out great but I turned out not too badly.  I should say I probably wouldn't be competitive for the job I have in today's job market though.

You can look at Mathscinet/Zentralblatt for my publication record.

Comment: You have papers in good journals, though.

Comment: I don't see anything bad about your cv.

Comment: Yes - but many people who now have CVs like the one I had in 2011 (when I got my current job) are not getting any offers.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say anyone can write a "large number of papers in good journals" using research ideas suggested by somebody else, either! If the ideas were that good, the advisor would have already pursued them. The kind of research ideas that can generate a perfectly good dissertation are nowhere near good enough to launch a proper research career. It's the standard case that a postdoc isn't a close collaborator of their postdoc host at all. They produce papers in the same way as any other fully trained mathematician.

Comment: Note that Kevin said "mathematician". I think he is right.  But maybe the answer differs by field.  For example, a postdoc in high-energy physics may be limited to experiments using the equipment already available in their PI's lab.

Comment: Yes, I definitely mean specifically mathematicians working on mainly theoretical projects here.

Answer (score 1):

I only have personal experience of the UK system, but from my acquaintance with those who have done postdocs elsewhere in Europe I would expect the situation there to be broadly similar. Here a postdoc is normally employed using money from a specific grant awarded to someone else (the PI). That person will act as a postdoc mentor and will also usually have a definite idea of potential problems for the postdoc to work on (related to the original grant proposal), although a postdoc will also continue to work on their own independent research. Thus I would expect a reasonable proportion of one's output during a postdoc position to be joint work with the PI, often involving problems suggested by the PI.